Login with Microsoft Azure in ionic app with angular and capacitor
I faced the problem login fails when I try to log in to Azure from the device. I think it's because the popup that MSAL shows for login is not allowed in Ionic.
Reviewing the forums I found several implementations but the most successful was the following Ionic and MSAL Authentication make some adjustments to the solution to be able to handle the response obtained and allow me to log in successfully
custom-navigation-client.ts

import { NavigationClient } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import {
  InAppBrowser,
  InAppBrowserObject,
} from "@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx";
import { Observer } from "rxjs";

export class CustomNavigationClient extends NavigationClient {
  constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser, private observer: Observer<any>) {
    super();
  }
  async navigateExternal(url: string, options: any) {
    // Cordova implementation
    if (window.hasOwnProperty("cordova")) {

      const browserOptions =
        "location=yes,mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=yes," +
        "shouldPauseOnSuspend=yes,usewkwebview=yes,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,fullscreen=yes,hidenavegationbuttons=yes";

      const browser: InAppBrowserObject = this.iab.create(
        url,
        "_blank",
        browserOptions
      );

      // Check if the appbrowser started a navigation
      browser.on("loadstart").subscribe((event) => {
        // Check if the url contains the #state login parameter
        console.log("event url", event.url);

        if (event.url.includes("#code")) {
          // Close the in app browser and redirect to localhost + the state parameter
          // msal-login is a fake route to trigger a page refresh
          browser.close();

          this.observer.next(event.url);
          this.observer.complete();
        }
      });

      // Suscribirse al evento "exit" del InAppBrowserObject
      browser.on("exit").subscribe((exit) => {
        // Completar el observable cuando se cierra el navegador sin interacción
        this.observer.next(exit);
        this.observer.complete();
      });
    } else {
      if (options.noHistory) {
        window.location.replace(url);
      } else {
        window.location.assign(url);
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

auth.service.ts

import { MsalService } from "@azure/msal-angular";
import { CustomNavigationClient } from "./custom-navigation-client";

constructor(
  private msalService: MsalService,
 ) {}

doLoginMicrosoft(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable<any>((observer) => {
      const navigationClient = new CustomNavigationClient(this.iab, observer);
      this.msalService.instance.setNavigationClient(navigationClient);

   this.msalService.instance.loginRedirect({
        scopes: ["User.Read"],
        prompt: "create",
      });
    });
  }

login.page.ts

import { AuthService } from "../_services/auth.service";

constructor(
 private auth: AuthService,
) {}

doMicrosoftLogin() {
    this.util.presentLoading();
    // storage is checked to not run the service again
    let client_info = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("client_info"));
    
    try {
      if (client_info == null) {
        this.auth.doLoginMicrosoft().subscribe(
          (client) => {
            
            if (typeof client == "string") {
              const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(client);
              // Obtén el valor del parámetro "client_info"
              const clientInfoEncoded = queryParams.get("client_info");

              // Decodes base64 encoded information
              if (clientInfoEncoded) {
                const clientInfoDecoded = atob(clientInfoEncoded);
                this.clientInfo = JSON.parse(clientInfoDecoded);
                
                // The Microsoft user information is set to the storage
                localStorage.setItem(
                  "client_info",
                  JSON.stringify(this.clientInfo)
                );

                // You can add your logic for login
              }
            }

            if (client.type == "exit") {
              this.util.dismissLoading();
              // Clear all sessionStorage data when the browser is closed without interacting
              sessionStorage.clear();
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            // Error handling if any occur during login
            console.error("Error durante el inicio de sesión:", error);
          }
        );
      } else {
        // Logic for login with the information stored in storage
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Manejar el error si ocurre
      this.util.dismissLoading();
      this.util.presentAlert(
        "¡Error!",
        error +
          " An error occurred while obtaining the data, please try again later"
      );
    }
  }

With the adjustment made to the code, the inconvenience when using msal-angular with redirect on Android devices is corrected
